# which sql command to use for exact result

Tags: mysql, join

i have 3 mysql tables
let me first show me them

```
t_answer_key
id        LESSON          KEY
1         CHEM            ABCDEDBCBDE
2         MATH            ABCDEDDEDEE
3         ENG             BCDEA
4         GER             DDDEA
5         RUS             BCDDD
6         SPA             AADDC
7         GEOM            ABCDDBED

t_test_count
id        LESSON         COUNT
1         CHEM           10
2         MATH           10
3         FRLNG          5 // FOREIGN LANGUAGES (ENG, GER, RUS, SPA, ...)
4         GEOM           8

t_frn_lng
id        FRG_LNG        LESSON
1         FRLNG          ENG
2         FRLNG          RUS
3         FRLNG          GER
4         FRLNG          SPA
```

So now let me ask my question.
which sql i must use to get the result which is shown below(sorry for my bad english)

```
LESSON    COUNT       KEY
CHEM      10          ABCDEDBCBDE
MATH      10          ABCDEDDEDEE
ENG       5           BCDEA
GER       5           DDDEA
RUS       5           BCDDD
SPA       5           AADDC
GEOM      8           ABCDDBED
```

Thank you..

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Is `LESSON` unique within each table?

Answer (score 0):

this is sample :

> SELECT `t_answer_key`.`Lesson` , `t_answer_key`.`key` , `t_test_count`.`COUNT` from `t_test_count` inner join  `t_answer_key` on `t_test_count`.`LESSON`=`t_answer_key`.`LESSON`

but [namco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/591826/namco)

is saying correct . you should have LESSON unique  in your table.

Comment: namco is actually the one who asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to keep LANGUAGES also in the t_test_count table. I can't see any advantage of t_frn_lng table.